# Выдает ошибку pyinstaller

Tags: pyinstaller

```
(venv) PS C:\project\pythonProject> pyinstaller main.py -F
185 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.1
185 INFO: Python: 3.10.5
251 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0
251 INFO: wrote C:\project\pythonProject\main.spec
253 INFO: UPX is not available.
254 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\project\\pythonProject']
693 INFO: checking Analysis
706 INFO: checking PYZ
716 INFO: checking PKG
716 INFO: Building because toc changed
717 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) main.pkg
1924 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) main.pkg completed successfully.
1925 INFO: Bootloader C:\project\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
1926 INFO: checking EXE
1926 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
1926 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
1926 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to C:\project\pythonProject\dist\main.exe.notanexecutable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\project\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 35, in pywin32error
    yield
  File "C:\project\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 229, in EndUpdateResource
    _resource._EndUpdateResource(handle, discard)
  File "C:\project\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\ctypes\_util.py", line 64, in check_false
    raise make_error(function, function_name)
OSError: [WinError 110] Системе не удается открыть указанное устройство или файл.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\project\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\project\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 178, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\project\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 59, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\project\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 842, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "C:\project\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 764, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\project\pythonProject\main.spec", line 24, in <module>
    exe = EXE(
  File "C:\project\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 524, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\project\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 173, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\project\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 625, in assemble
    winresource.RemoveAllResources(build_name)
  File "C:\project\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 245, in RemoveAllResources
    win32api.EndUpdateResource(hsrc, False)
  File "C:\project\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 228, in EndUpdateResource
    with _pywin32error():
  File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 153, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "C:\project\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
    raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (110, 'EndUpdateResourceW', 'Системе не удается открыть указанное устройство или файл.')
```

Comment: Забыл добавить, пользуюсь Pycharm

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему установкой UPX. Качал от сюда https://github.com/upx/upx/releases/